# Positive primes represented by indefinite binary quadratic form

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Neil Sloane asked me about commands in computer languages to find the (positive) primes represented by indefinite binary quadratic forms. So I wrote something in C++ that works. This is for the OEIS, these primes go into sequences... Note that, within a few hours, another guy had run the tables much higher with a one-line Maple command. Some days it does not pay to get up.

I thought of one I really do not understand. Discriminant $205$ has four classes of forms, $$ \langle 1, 13, -9 \rangle, \; \langle -1, 13, 9 \rangle, \;  \langle 3, 13, -3 \rangle, \; \langle -3, 13, 3 \rangle.   $$

The third and fourth are opposites so in the same genus, although distinct. The first two are in the principal genus, but they are not opposites, one is $-1$ times the other; in particular, they get diffeent positive primes, although both do residues $\pmod 5$ and $\pmod {41}.$ For $\langle 1, 13, -9 \rangle$ we get
$$ 1,5,59,131,139,241,269,271,359,409, \ldots,  $$ while for $\langle -1, 13, 9 \rangle$ we get
$$ 31,41,61,251,349,379,389,401,419,431, \ldots.  $$

For positive forms, low class number, there are polynomials, such as in Cox's book, such that primes represented by the principal form are those for which the polynomial factors a certain way. For a prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3,$ Gauss showed that $2$ is a cubic residue if an only if $p = u^2 + 27 v^2.$ Jacobi showed that $3$ is a cubic residue if an only if $p = u^2 + uv + 61 v^2.$ All I found in Henri Cohen's tables was the fact that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt {205})$ has class number $2$ and $L_K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt 5),$ appendix 12C on pages 533 and 534. See related information at [IT'S A LINK.](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/inhom.html)

Let's see, $34$ is the smallest number where it is a surprise that there is no solution to $x^2 - 34 y^2 = -1.$ The smallest such odd number is $205,$ as there is no solution to $x^2 - 205 y^2 = -1.$ For prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ there is always a solution to $x^2 - p y^2 = -1.$ Proof in Mordell's book. Anyway, this is why $\langle 1, 13, -9 \rangle, \; \langle -1, 13, 9 \rangle$ are distinct classes.

So, that is the question, can I distinguish the represented (positive) primes by factoring some polynomial mod these primes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Class field theory promises such a polynomial (more properly,
such a number field $H$, since a polynomial generating $H$ might have to err
on the first few primes, though in our case it turns out there's a
polynomial with no exceptional primes).  The proof is effective,
though the recipe is often hard to carry out.  So I attempted an end run
by asking [this database](http://hobbes.la.asu.edu/NFDB)
for number fields of degree $8$ and discriminant $205^4$,
and was rewarded with
$$
x^8 + 15 x^6 + 48 x^4 + 15 x^2 + 1,
$$
which generates an unramified normal extension 
$H \, / \, {\bf Q}(\sqrt{205})$ with the right Galois group.
This polynomial matches your list exactly: the **gp** code

```
{
forprime(p=1,1000,
   f = factormod(x^8+15*x^6+48*x^4+15*x^2+1, p)[,1];
   if(vecmax(vector(#f,n,poldegree(f[n])))==1,print(p))
)
}
```

returns your 5, 59, 131, 139, 241, 269, 271, 359, 409,
and then continues 541, 569, 599, 661, 701, 761, 859, 881, 911, 941,
still in exact agreement with the list of primes
represented by $u^2 + 13uv - 9v^2$.

[*added later*] That **gp** code checks whether 
all factors of $P_8(x) := x^8 + 15 x^6 + 48 x^4 + 15 x^2 + 1 \bmod p$
have degree $1$.  Since the polynomial is Galois, it would have been
sufficient to check that one factor is linear:

```
{
forprime(p=3,1000,
   if(poldegree(factormod(x^8+15*x^6+48*x^4+15*x^2+1, p)[1,1])==1, print(p))
)
}
```

(I "cheated" a tad by excluding $p=2$, which is a factor of the
discriminant of $P_8$ but not of the number field.)
The Galois group of $P_8$ is dihedral, so one can find
a quartic polynomial $P_4$ with the same Galois closure that
factors completely mod $p$ **iff** $P_8$ does; such a polynomial
was exhibited by **NAME_IN_CAPS** answering the follow-up 
[Question 171846](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171846).
Alternatively, we know already that $p$ is (either $5$ or) a quadratic
residue of both $5$ and $41$, so by Quadratic Reciprocity $5$ and $41$
have square roots mod $p$, which means that $p$ factors completely in
${\bf Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{41})$.  And indeed $x^2$ generates that field
and equals (some conjugate of)
$$
-\frac14 (15 + 3 \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{41} + \sqrt{205});
$$
so you can also test whether $p$ is represented by $u^2 + 13uv - 9v^2$
by computing $\sqrt{5} \bmod p$ and $\sqrt{41} \bmod p$
(if they don't exist then there's no representation),
and then testing whether $-(15 + 3 \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{41} + \sqrt{205})$
is a square mod $p$.

Comment: For the very similar discriminant 221 and $x^2 + 13 x y - 13 y^2, $ I was surprised to find that $$ f(x) = x^8 +  x^6 - 4 x^5 - 38 x^4 - 2 x^3 + 123 x^2 -34 x + 17, $$ has a repeated root $\pmod {101},$ although still linear factors, seven of them with one of them squared. Is that allowed? After that it is always 8 roots. This time the primes are $ 17,101,103,127,179,251,263,373,433,$

Comment: For 221, the quartic $$ x^4 +  x^3 +  x^2 + 2 x + 4 $$ behaves well

Comment: The repeated root mod $101$ is an example of my warning that
"a polynomial generating [the Hilbert class field] $H$ might have to
err on the first few primes" if $H$ has no generator $x$ such that
${\bf Z}[x]$ is the full ring of integers of $H$.  A better choice
for this purpose is $x^8 + 34 x^6 + 83 x^4 + 34 x^2 + 1$,
which has spurious repeated roots only mod $2$ and $3$
(and as it happens no linear factors modulo either of these primes).
Then $x+1/x$ generates a quartic isomorphic with the one you found
with coefficients $1,1,1,2,4$.

Comment: Cool. Thanks, Noam. That does look much better. I found my degree eight on that website you mentioned, by putting in $221^4.$ Actually, the first time it thought i meant 2214 and complained. i decided it was better to multiply out the number.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the quadratic number field $K$  with discriminant $D = pq$,
where $p$ and $q$ are primes $\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ (all results below
hold after a suitable modification also for $p = 2$). By results due 
to Dirichlet and Scholz, The fundamental unit of this field has norm

- $-1$ if $(p/q) = -1$
- $+1$ if $(p/q) = +1$ and $(p/q)_4 (q/p)_4 = -1$
- $-1$ if $(p/q) = +1$ and $(p/q)_4 = (q/p)_4 = -1$

Here $(q/2)_4$ is $+1$ or $-1$ according as $p$ is congruent to $1$
or $9$ modulo $16$.

In the case $(p/q) = -1$, the Hilbert $2$-class field coincides with
the genus field $K^* = Q(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q}\,)$. This is also the Hilbert
$2$-class field in the usual sense if  $(p/q) = +1$ and $(p/q)_4 (q/p)_4 = -1$;
in this case, however, there is a quadratic extension of the genus field
unramified at finite primes, which can be constructed explicitly by
solving the diophantine equation $x^2 - 4py^2 = q$ and setting
$K = K^*(\sqrt{\mu})$ for $\mu = x + 2y\sqrt{p}$, where the sign of
$x$ is chosen in such a way that $\mu$ is congruent to a square mod $4$,
i.e., such that $x + 2y \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. In this case this means
that $x$ is negative.

For the smallest discriminants, the corresponding elements are

- $D = 2 \cdot 17$: $\mu = -5 + 2 \sqrt{2}$;
- $D = 5 \cdot 41$: $\mu = -11 + 4 \sqrt{5}$;
- $D = 13 \cdot 17$: $\mu = -9 + 2 \sqrt{17}$;
- $D = 5 \cdot 61$: $\mu = -9 + 2 \sqrt{5}$.

Noam's generator in the case $D = 205$, by the way, is 
$\sqrt{\varepsilon_{205}} \cdot \omega$, where 
$\sqrt{\varepsilon_{205}} = \frac12(3\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{41})$
and $\omega = \frac12(1+\sqrt{5})$.

It is possible to construct the corresponding polynomials, but for your purpose it is
better to work with the generators, as already Noam has pointed out.